# Laravel URL Language Prefix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to set up two languages for my site. I have read around (http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=7458, http://laravel.io/forum/02-20-2014-how-to-make-switching-language-button) and I can't seem to get the prefix part of it working.

The default language if set or selected:

```
/news
```

If Chinese is selected:

```
/zh/news
```

My filters.php:

```
App::before(function($request) {
    // default browser language
    $language = substr($request->server->get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);

    // language set from route
    if (null !== $request->segment(1)) {
        $routeLanguage = $request->segment(1);
        if (in_array($routeLanguage, Config::get('app.languages'))) {
            $language = $routeLanguage;
        }
    }
    //return $language;
    // set the language
    Config::set('app.locale', $language);
    App::setLocale($language);
});
```

The language selector:

```
class LanguageController extends BaseController {

    public function select($lang) {
        Session::put('lang', $lang);

        return Redirect::route('home');
    }

}
```

And my routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@home', 'as' => 'home'));

Route::get('language/{lang}', array(
    'as' => 'language.select',
    'uses' => 'LanguageController@select'
        )
);
```

My two language links are setting the variable correctly, but I don't know how to finish it off the way I want (I want the language slug in the URL for SEO reasons).

How can I achieve this?